# need to develop utility independent of technology used for website development

Tags: security, encryption, web, cryptography

I need a utility to be given to my customer having site name A.com where he can decry-pt messages passed from my own site (i.e. B.com), which is build in Java technology.

Utility should be independent of technologies used by customer web site for their development.

Question: What technology should be used for developing such a Utility ?

Note: I have read that JavaScript is not good for cryptography.

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to use an existing, tried-and-tested protocol. TLS is a good choice for securing communication between two parties.

If, for some reason, you cannot use an existing protocol, you'll have to design your own, and describe it in such detail that others can implement it on their platforms. But this is very far from ideal for several reasons. Designing cryptographic protocols is hard, and even experts regularly get it wrong. Implementing cryptographic protocols is hard too, and experts often also get this wrong. There is simply no way a non-cryptographer could design or implement a secure protocol.

Comment: Hi I came across this link is it worth implementing ?

Comment: No. Just use the inbuilt TLS support in the browser. Please see this: http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/

Comment: Please find given link in support of [JavaScript Cryptography] (http://hellais.wordpress.com/2011/12/27/how-to-improve-javascript-cryptography/)

Comment: One more document in support of Java Script Cryptography : [link] (http://log.nadim.cc/?p=33)

Comment: The main point of the Matasano article is that browser JavaScript cryptography is entirely redundant, because you always need TLS to deliver the scripts safely. But with TLS, you already have a secure communication channel.